# How to determine how an assembly was built

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly

I'm using VS2010/2012 and I was wondering if there is a way (perhaps using reflection) to see how an assembly is build.

When I run in Debug, I use the `#if DEBUG` to write debug information out to the console.

However, when you end up with a bunch of assemblies, is there then a way to see how they where build? Getting the version number is easy, but I haven't been able to find out how to check the build type.

Comment: What do you mean by "check the build type" ?

Comment: And what are you *really* interested in finding out? (Conditional compilation symbols? Optimization options? Debugging options?)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186613/how-to-check-if-an-assembly-was-built-using-debug-or-release-configuration

Comment: @Dennis, I thought I had done a thoroughly search on this - obviously not, sorry, but you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Verakso did you read my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 ways:

```
private bool IsAssemblyDebugBuild(string filepath)
{
    return IsAssemblyDebugBuild(Assembly.LoadFile(Path.GetFullPath(filepath)));
}

private bool IsAssemblyDebugBuild(Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (var attribute in assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false))
    {
        var debuggableAttribute = attribute as DebuggableAttribute;
        if(debuggableAttribute != null)
        {
            return debuggableAttribute.IsJITTrackingEnabled;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or using assemblyinfo metadata:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif
```

Or using a constant with `#if DEBUG` in code

```
#if DEBUG
        public const bool IsDebug = true;
#else
        public const bool IsDebug = false;
#endif
```

I prefer the second way so i can read it both by code and with windows explorer

Comment: I did se you answer, but I also read the original post, and blog post, and ended up with at slightly modified version of `IsAssemblyDebugBuild`that looked like this:
`return assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(x => (x as DebuggableAttribute) != null ? (x as DebuggableAttribute).IsJITTrackingEnabled : false);`

Answer (score 3):

Once they are compiled, you can't, unless you put the metadata yourself.

For example, you could use either [`AssemblyConfigurationAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf72c7kz.aspx) or .NET 4.5's [`AssemblyMetadataAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblymetadataattribute.aspx)

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif
```

or

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyMetadata("DefinedVariable", "DEBUG")]
#endif
```