# What is the difference between IsDebuggingEnabled and Debugger.IsAttached

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Are there any differences between `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` and `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`?

If so, what are the exact differences besides the fact that one is only for web applications while the other works in all kind of projects?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) is about the compilation setting in the web.config. [`Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached(v=vs.110).aspx) defines if there is actually an active debugger listening to the information coming from the web server.

See the explanation at [DotnetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/isdebuggingenabled) regarding `HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled`:

> Debug mode is not the default. ... When you do not set debug="true" in Web.config, the site is compiled in Release mode.

Regarding your question why the first 'one is only for web applications': web applications have the ability to compile at run-time, while all other .NET products are pre-compiled. Because of this, you can define in the web.config if the build is done in Debug or Release mode. This is a ASP.NET only option, so the property is only available there.

As answer to your second question, why the first option is only for ASP.NET: There is also a way for a Windows application to check it's build status: by checking the [`DebuggableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) as explained in [How to check if an assembly was built using Debug or Release configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186613/how-to-check-if-an-assembly-was-built-using-debug-or-release-configuration).

Comment: No, no more questions. Btw, I did not ask "why the first option is only for ASP.NET". I was asking for more differences between those two options. Anyway, thanks for pointing out the `DebuggableAttribute` on windows applications.

Comment: @modiX: I updated the answer with a paragraph regarding your question.

Answer (score 7):

`IsDebuggingEnabled` refers to "debug mode" which does not necessarily mean a debugger is actually attached. You can set ASP.NET websites into debug mode by setting `<compilation debug="true">` in your `web.config` file.

When a website is in debug mode, JIT optimizations are not applied to code contained within your view files (.aspx, .cshtml, etc) as well as any runtime-compiled code-behind files or the `App_Code` directory. There are also other effects.

Comment: Thanks for additionally pointing out the differences of debug mode and without debug mode (about the JIT compiler). It accompanies the fact why a 2nd separate debug configuration makes sense, so it accompanies the fact we got two ways of checking for debug mode.